# how set unix alias with current directory works on every path

Tags: unix, path, find, cygwin, alias

i have this alias that works on "/" directory but stops working when path changes

```
    alias exesh='chmod +x $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sh')'
```

I am a newbie with Unix so any help is welcome
*I'm using cygwin, if can be this the  issue *
Bash, on this problem, says me this

```
    find: paths must precede expression: 2b.sh
    Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
    chmod: missing operand after '+x'
    Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

but if i paste on command line `chmod +x $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sh')` it works properly, so i think it depends on current directory `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with suggestion on using find -exec i finally my problem solved. The solution is:
`alias exesh='find . -name "*.sh"  -exec /bin/chmod +x {} \;'`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alias exesh='chmod +x $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '"'"'*.sh'"'"')'
```

Your issue was that you had ticks - `'` inside your ticks. Ticks and quotes - `"` may be concatenated freely, so that is a reliable way of coding ticks within ticks.

I was also going to suggest using `find -exec` instead of command expansion, but I can't find a way to escape the `+` character from `find` in such a construction.

Comment: according to your suggestion I tried to change the external ticks with back ticks and now works

Comment: You now have `alias exesh=\`chmod +x $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '"'"'*.sh'"'"')\``?

Comment: no, now i have: `alias exesh=\`chmod +x $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sh')\``

Comment: I don't think that will really work. `\`command\`` is the same as `$(command)`. It may have worked in the directory you created the alias, but I bet it won't work otherwise. What happens when you enter `alias exesh`?